# Objective C: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000550c0

Tags: ios, sorting, crash

Here, m try to sort the array when refersh the tableview but is crash the application when refresh tableview.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFArray
>   sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6080000550c0'

```
@interface TableViewController () {
     NSMutableArray *returnArray; 
} 
@end




- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Unique",nil]];
    returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    returnArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for(Resgistration* reg in returnArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", reg);
        NSLog(@"%@", reg.roshan);
    }
 [self.tableView reloadData];
    UIColor *gray = [UIColor colorWithRed:234/255.0 green:234/255.0 blue:234/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Please Wait"];
    [refreshControl setBackgroundColor:gray];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(sortArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

}


 - (void)sortArray
    {

        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
        NSMutableArray *sortDescriptior = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sort, nil];
        [returnArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptior]; // crash the app

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; 
    }
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: it seems that your returnArray is type of class `PFArray` please check it, and i think that this class `PFArray` maybe don't have this method

Comment: retutnrArray is NSMutableArray so what PFArray?

Comment: please post the `returnArray` declaration

Comment: question is edit please check it.

Comment: returnArray in data is available see: }),
<Resgistration: 0x6080000cb1a0> (entity: Resgistration; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://ACB5647F-9A39-49E5-AEEB-3AB97C2F4152/Resgistration/p2> ; data: {
    address = jhjh;
    contact = jh;
    email = jkhjkh;
    hobby = jh;
    name = jhjhjk;
    number = 2;
    otheNo = jh;
    roshan = "0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://ACB5647F-9A39-49E5-AEEB-3AB97C2F4152/Unique/p2>";
})

Comment: Check the answer provided by @PuneetSharma

Comment: @PuneetSharma say _PFArray is subclass of NSArray but i can't define NSArray. Reinier Melian

Comment: Please post all your code that  involve returnArray

Comment: @GanganiRoshan: I said you have assigned the instance of _PFArray in returnArray somewhere in your code, most probably where you are fetching stuff from CoreData. There you must use mutableCopy version instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_PFArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` and is immutable. You can use `sortUsingDescriptors:` on mutable array only, hence the crash.

It looks like somewhere along the code you have assigned instance of CoreData array inside  `returnArray` variable. There you must use `mutableCopy` method to convert the immutable array to its mutable version, something like this:

```
returnArray = [<data array fetched from core data> mutableCopy];
```

**Edit after looking at complete code**

```
returnArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: but declaration in returnArray is NSMutableArray so why is crash?